# How auto-preview as a value changes in Adobe Photoshop CC?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

For example, if I try to change the color of a text object it only updates the color of the text when I release mouse button. Similarly, when I am changing the opacity, it updates the new graphic only after I release mouse button.

This is quite annoying when I am just trying to find the right color/value and don't want to click mouse button down and up for each value I choose.

Is there an option to auto-refresh the document on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

One option concerning Opacity would be to right click on your layer of interest, then select "Blending Options..." . This will bring you to a window titled "Layer Styles". Here you can actively see any live changes being made to your layer of interest. There are many different styles/blending options you can alter in this window. 
Hope this helps!